# Kendo UI Grid local data source column sort by default

Tags: kendo-grid

Trying to set a default sort column on my kendo UI grid from a local datasource. I've read all over that I should be putting:

```
sort: { field: "price", dir: "desc" }
```

onto the data source. I've tried this and it still isn't working (see bottom of following example).

Here's my code in full, where am I going wrong?

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: [
                    {
                        date: "Feb 13 2014",
                        price: 5,
                    },
                    {
                        date: "Feb 15 2014",
                        price: 7,
                    },
                    {
                        date: "Feb 12 2014",
                        price: 6,
                    }
                ],
                height:500,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: false,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "date",
                        title: "Date"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "price",
                        title: "Price",
                    }
                ],
                sort: {field: "price", dir: "desc"}
            });
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are defining the `sort` line in the wrong place. You're putting it as one of the grid's properties, but it is (as you said) one of the datasource's property.

Put it as a child of the datasource property:

```js
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: [{
            date: "Feb 13 2014",
            price: 5,
        }, {
            date: "Feb 15 2014",
            price: 7,
        }, {
            date: "Feb 12 2014",
            price: 6,
        }],
        sort: {
            field: "price",
            dir: "desc"
        }
    },
    height: 500,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "date",
        title: "Date"
    }, {
        field: "price",
        title: "Price",
    }],
});
```

If it still doesn't work, I can provide a jsFiddle for you to work around with.

Comment: can you give me jsFiddle

Comment: make sure you get the correct capitalization on the field name. If you use a model in asp.net core, LastName becomes lastName in javascript.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Telerik MVC Control which is finally rendered to Kendo UI

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("City").Ascending()) // <-- initial sort expression
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Home"))
    )
```

Comment: Note that the string inside Add (eg. City) was the name of the field the column is bound to

Comment: Multiple sorting example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437920/sorting-kendo-grid-on-multiple-columns